# How to get x5c from RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, jwt, x509certificate

I am using [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) for signing [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) tokens, and everying works fine. Now following the [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) and [JWK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) spec, I need provide [`x5c`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.7) value to client for validating the signature of the signed [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). So, How can I generate the [`x5c`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.7) value given I have a valid [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) instance in C#?

I found [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.exportparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) method can export all parameters of the RSA, but have no idea how to compose the [`x5c`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517#section-4.7) value based on that.

Answer (score 0):

x5c is the X.509 chain, which requires that you have a certificate (instead of a raw RSA key).

If you have an X509Certificate2 object which you used for private key retrieval, or otherwise have a certificate representing that key, you can build the chain via

```
X509Chain chain = new X509Chain()
bool success = chain.Build(cert);

if (!success)
    throw new Exception("eep");
```

Then for each `chain.ChainElements` value, take the Certificate property RawValue property (and base64 encode it).

I didn't look at the spec enough to know if you should skip the first element (your cert) and/or the last one (the root cert). But that should be enough to get started.